# ExtJs4 How do I create a dynamic function in a loop

Tags: javascript, dynamic, extjs4

I have a MVC app in Ext 4.2.1 where I am creating a dynamic grid using reconfigure. It works well but I am stuck on how to add filters to the grid using the Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature. All examples I have seen are hard coded.

In my situation both my store and grid columns are not known until the user makes a selection. I then build it on the fly in a for loop using the following function:

```
    onBuildGrid: function() {

        var store = this.getStore('Keys');
        var grid = this.getIndexGrid();
        var rvabrep = this.getStore('Rvabreps');

        var columnModel = [];
        var fields = [];
        var triggerFn = function() {
            this.setValue('');
            var store = this.up('tablepanel').store;
            store.clearFilter();
        };

        for (i = 0; i < store.data.items.length; i++) {
        dataIndex = store.data.items[i].data.IDX;
        text = store.data.items[i].data.IDXDESC;

        columnModel.push({
            text: text,
            dataIndex: dataIndex,

        });
        fields.push({
            name: dataIndex
        });
    }

    rvabrep.model.setFields(fields);
    grid.reconfigure(rvabrep, columnModel);
```

In the push function I need to add the following code, but can't figure out how to get a variable inside the function for the keyup listener. The OnTriggerClick function worked, but it was easy to make a variable of it because it's static.

I thought I could use the same technique for the keyup function, if I could only figure out how to do it.

I need a javascript genius to the rescue!!!  Thanks!

```
       items: {
            xtype: 'trigger',
            triggerCls: 'x-form-clear-trigger', 
            onTriggerClick: triggerFn
            flex : 1,
            margin: 2,
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            listeners: {
                keyup: function() {
                    var store = this.up('tablepanel').store;
                    store.clearFilter();
                    if (this.value) {
                        store.filter({
                            //property needs to be the variable "dataindex"
                            property      : ?this_needs_to_be_a variable?
                            value         : this.value,
                            anyMatch      : false,
                            caseSensitive : false
                        });
                    }
                },
                buffer: 500
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this instead of having it be a variable?

```
this.up("gridcolumn").dataIndex;
```

Comment: Not sure but I may give that a try just to see because in the mean time I figured it out.  Since the column has an item config, I created a custom property called dataIndex and set it to the variable dataIndex.  I was then able to build the keyup function as a variable outside my loop and use it to filter the store.  I'd post that code but I can't figure out how to get it in this comment as code.  Every time I hit return it finishes my comment..  Thanks for your reply. I am curious to see if what you suggested will work.